# Remove fuzzy duplicates from big dataset

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a CSV file with a number of records. Each record represents some person. It has `first_name`, `last_name`, and other details.
My goal is to remove duplicates from this data but in a smart way. Records come from different sources and duplicates can contain different information.
I simplified the problem within example below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "Anna", "Smyth", "01/03", "NY"), 
        (2, "Anna", "Smyth", "01/03", ""), 
        (3, "Anna", "Smyth", "01/03", "NY"),         
        (4, "Max", "Anderson", "12/04", "Boston"), 
        (5, "Max", "Anderson", "", "London"), 
        (6, "Max", "Anderson", "06/07", ""),         
        (7, "Sarah", "Nicolson", "02/09", ""), 
        (8, "Sarah", "Jonson", "", "Mexico"), 
        (9, "Sarah", "Jonson", "01/08", "Dallas"), 
    ],
    ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "birthday", "city")
)
df.show()

+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
| id|first_name|last_name|birthday|  city|
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
|  1|      Anna|    Smyth|   01/03|    NY|
|  2|      Anna|    Smyth|   01/03|      |
|  3|      Anna|    Smyth|   01/03|    NY|
|  4|       Max| Anderson|   12/04|Boston|
|  5|       Max| Anderson|        |London|
|  6|       Max| Anderson|   06/07|      |
|  7|     Sarah| Nicolson|   02/09|      |
|  8|     Sarah|   Jonson|        |Mexico|
|  9|     Sarah|   Jonson|   01/08|Dallas|
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
```

I'd like to group records by `first_name` and `last_name` and then do some comparison to consider if record is a duplicate or not.
If few records have same `first_name` and `last_name`, I want to check `birthday` and, if it equals - it's duplicates.
If one or record has `birthday` populated, another one - not, it's duplicate. If both (or more) records have empty `birthday` - it's duplicates.
I'm ignoring `city` field in comparison, but when considering duplicates, I want to leave "richest" record, record that has more fields populated.
If records have same names but different birthdays - it's not duplicates.

For example, above, I'd like to get:

```
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
| id|first_name|last_name|birthday|  city|
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
|  1|      Anna|    Smyth|   01/03|    NY|
|  4|       Max| Anderson|   12/04|Boston|
|  6|       Max| Anderson|   06/07|      |
|  7|     Sarah| Nicolson|   02/09|      |
|  9|     Sarah|   Jonson|   01/08|Dallas|
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
```

In real problem I have much more fields - about 70 and some of them should be obligatory to match, some - not. Number of records I need to process - around 100 million.
I'm considering using pyspark, but any technology welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can create group column `grp` for each row by concatenating columns `first_name#last_name#birthday` where `birthday` is replaced by max from partition [`first_name`, `last_name]` if it's null or empty string:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w1 = Window.partitionBy("first_name", "last_name").orderBy()

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "grp",
    F.concat_ws(
        "#",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        F.coalesce(F.expr("nullif(birthday, '')"), F.max("birthday").over(w1))
    )
).withColumn(
    "rich_columns",
    F.array(
        *[F.col(c) for c in df.columns if c not in ["id", "first_name", "last_name"]]
    )
)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+---+----------+---------+--------+------+--------------------+---------------+
#|id |first_name|last_name|birthday|city  |grp                 |rich_columns   |
#+---+----------+---------+--------+------+--------------------+---------------+
#|1  |Anna      |Smyth    |01/03   |NY    |Anna#Smyth#01/03    |[01/03, NY]    |
#|2  |Anna      |Smyth    |01/03   |      |Anna#Smyth#01/03    |[01/03, ]      |
#|3  |Anna      |Smyth    |01/03   |NY    |Anna#Smyth#01/03    |[01/03, NY]    |
#|7  |Sarah     |Nicolson |02/09   |      |Sarah#Nicolson#02/09|[02/09, ]      |
#|8  |Sarah     |Jonson   |        |Mexico|Sarah#Jonson#01/08  |[, Mexico]     |
#|9  |Sarah     |Jonson   |01/08   |Dallas|Sarah#Jonson#01/08  |[01/08, Dallas]|
#|4  |Max       |Anderson |12/04   |Boston|Max#Anderson#12/04  |[12/04, Boston]|
#|5  |Max       |Anderson |        |London|Max#Anderson#12/04  |[, London]     |
#|6  |Max       |Anderson |06/07   |      |Max#Anderson#06/07  |[06/07, ]      |
#+---+----------+---------+--------+------+--------------------+---------------+
```

The columns `birthday` and `city` are also used to create an array column `rich_columns` that will be used to prioritize rows with max info not empty/null.

Then, perform a row number using the group column created above and ordering by the size of `rich_columns` array:

```
w2 = Window.partitionBy("grp").orderBy(
    F.expr("size(filter(rich_columns, x -> nullif(x, '') is not null))").desc()
)

df2 = df1.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w2)) \
    .filter("rn = 1") \
    .drop("grp", "rn", "rich_columns")

df2.show()

#+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
#| id|first_name|last_name|birthday|  city|
#+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
#|  7|     Sarah| Nicolson|   02/09|      |
#|  1|      Anna|    Smyth|   01/03|    NY|
#|  9|     Sarah|   Jonson|   01/08|Dallas|
#|  6|       Max| Anderson|   06/07|      |
#|  4|       Max| Anderson|   12/04|Boston|
#+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
```

In a real-world application, you should transform columns `last_name`, `first_name` to uppercase and strip accents (if any) before doing this.